# Mutually exclusive regex validator for textboxes in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a form containing many `text`fields. Among them there is a field for the `name` and another for the `surname`. Both of them are checked for valid characters (only letters are allowed). However, I would like to only display one warning if both fields have invalid data.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Name" placeholder="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Surname" placeholder="Surname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic"  ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Name" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]+$" Text="Invalid name!" /> 
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic"  ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Surname" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]+$"  Text="Invalid name!" />
```

If I enter the name Amy Adams it shouldn't show a warning.
If I enter Amy Ada3s it should say `'Invalid name!'`.
Similarly if I enter A3y Adams. 
Now if I enter A3y Ada3s, the warning message should only be displayed once.

If possible, not using jquery or other frameworks. Just `javascript` or `asp.net` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net has a solution for circumstances like these, in the form of the `CustomValidator` control.

> The **CustomValidator** control allows you to create a validation control with customized validation logic.

You should [always] specify server-side logic, and [optionally] client-side logic.

*Read more: [CustomValidator Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)*

**HTML**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Name" placeholder="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Surname" placeholder="Surname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<br />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="BothNamesValidator" runat="server" Text="Invalid Name!" Display="Dynamic"
    ClientValidationFunction="BothNames_ClientValidate" 
    OnServerValidate="BothNames_ServerValidate" 
    />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function BothNames_ClientValidate(source, args) {
    var name = document.getElementById('<%= Name.ClientID %>').value;
    var surname = document.getElementById('<%= Surname.ClientID %>').value;
    args.IsValid = (/[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(name) && /[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(surname));
}
```

**C#**

```
protected void BothNames_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    var name = Name.Text;
    var surname = Surname.Text;
    args.IsValid = Regex.IsMatch(name, "[a-zA-Z]+$") && Regex.IsMatch(surname, "[a-zA-Z]+$");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the single logical block where both the fields should be checked.. Sample code below

```
if(!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test($("#Name")) || !/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test($("#Surname"))) {
   console.log("Text is invalid");
}
```